# Why are there no tv projectors with optical out?

Tags: home-theater, television, audio, projector

I must be missing something obvious here.

I'm looking at TV projector for a home theater setup and non of them seem to have optical out. I initially thought it was because I was just looking at the cheap ones, but it seems even the higher end ones lack optical out. They usually just have analogue L/R output or a 3.5mm jack.

Why is this? Many newer TVs have optical out. How am I supposed to connect digital surround sound speakers to a projector?

For example right now I have an old wii, blue ray player, and chrome cast connected to a TV and the TV is connected via optical to the speakers. I need the optical from the TV because non of those devices support optical directly. How do I do this with a TV projector with no digital audio support?

Comment: Because the market hasn't demanded it. Because the manufacturers do no believe adding it would significantly increase their profit. Feel free to contact them directly and try to persuade them otherwise. Grumping about it here is of no value.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, this question is off-topic here, and I'm not sure what other SE site would be more appropriate.

Comment: I suspect most just want to feed video up to that spot in the ceiling the projector hangs from. It's really much more convenient to have all the other connections (for speakers / amplifiers / media players etc) down low in an equipment cabinet.  That's only speculation tho, and since speculation is the only possible answer, makes your question off topic.  You might try hardware recommendations, "media center" might be close to on topic there.

Answer (score 1):

Use an external tuner/switcher/amplifier.